Invariance of spacetime interval when using Rindler coordinates
In the previous question I asked why it is not possible to derive Rindler coordinates using Lorentz transforms and I think I found an answer.
Lorentz transforms in standard configuration
$$t'=\gamma\left(t-\frac{vx}{c^2}\right)\qquad x'=\gamma(x-vt)$$
satisfies this relation $-c^2t^2+x^2=-c^2t'^2+x'^2$. However, if we instead use Rindler coordinate transforms (not sure what's the appropriate terminology for this):
$$t'=\frac{c}{\alpha}\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{ct}{x}\right)\qquad x'=\sqrt{x^2-c^2t^2}$$
it seems like $-c^2t^2+x^2=-c^2t'^2+x'^2$ no longer hold true:
$$-c^2t'^2+x'^2 = -\left(\frac{c^2}{\alpha}\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{ct}{x}\right)\right)^2 + x^2-c^2t^2.$$
The first term is not equal to zero, so RHS cannot simplify to $-c^2t^2+x^2$, unlike Lorentz transforms.
Assuming there are no issues in my calculations, I wonder is there any intuitive explanation to why the spacetime interval is not invariant when using Rindler coordinate transforms.

If you change your coordinate system from coordinates $x^\mu$ to coordinates $\tilde x^{\tilde \mu}$ your metric transforms as
$$g_{\mu \nu}(x) \mapsto \tilde g_{\mu\nu}(\tilde x)
= \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial \tilde x^\mu} \frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial \tilde x^\nu} g_{\alpha \beta}(x[\tilde x])$$
Now,
in special cases it happens that $g_{\mu\nu} = \tilde g_{\mu\nu}$.E.g., if your metric is given by the Minkowski metric $\eta = \begin{pmatrix}-1 &&&\\ &1&&\\&&1&\\&&&1\end{pmatrix}$ and if your coordinate change is a Poincaré transformation
$$ \tilde x^\mu = \Lambda^\mu{}_{\nu} x^\nu + \xi^\mu $$
then it just happens that $\eta=g =\tilde g$.
Now, this is not the case for Rindler coordinates. Furthermore, the Rindler coordinates are curvilinear thus the length of infinitesimal translation $x^\mu \mapsto x^\mu+ d x^\mu$ does not only depend on $d x^\mu$ but also on $x^\mu$ because the metric is $g_{\mu\nu}$ is not constant. In general, it is given by
$$
d\tau^2 = d x^\mu d x^\nu g_{\mu \nu}(x)\,.
$$
For example, the line element of Rindler coordinates is given by $\mathrm{d}\tau^{2}=-(\alpha x)^{2}\mathrm{d}t'^{2}+\mathrm{d}x'^{2}+\mathrm{d}y'^{2}+\mathrm{d}z'^{2}$ which is not constant as it depends on $x'^2$
The moral is that one should not think of Rindler coordinates as Minkowski coordinates. In particular, one should not expect the line element to be given by $d\tau^2 = -dt'^2 + dx'^2+ dy'^2 +dz'^2 = d {x'}^\mu d {x'}^\nu \eta_{\mu \nu}(x')$ in rindler coordinates, since the metric in rindler coordinates is $g' \neq \eta$
Note that the same happens if you switch to curvilinear coordinates of euclidian $\mathbb R^3$. E.g,the metric in polar coordinates cylinder coordinates $\rho,\varphi,z$ is given by
$$g = \begin{pmatrix}
1&&\\ & \rho&&\\&&&1\end{pmatrix}$$.
All of this is just an artifact of working in different coordinate systems, the length or proper time of a path will be the same regardless of the coordinate system used to express it.

Thanks. There are two typos: (1) $\mathrm{d}\tau^{2}=-(\alpha x)^{2}\mathrm{d}t'^{2}+\mathrm{d}x'^{2}+\mathrm{d}y'^{2}+\mathrm{d}z'^{2}$ should be $\mathrm{d}\tau^{2}=-(\alpha x')^{2}\mathrm{d}t'^{2}+\mathrm{d}x'^{2}+\mathrm{d}y'^{2}+\mathrm{d}z'^{2}$ (2) In metric for cylindral coordinates, the middle element should be $\rho^2$.

I found out that the quantity
$$S=\int ds=\int\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu}$$
(integrate over straight line path from $(0,0)$ to $(ct,x)$.)
is invariant under coordinate transforms.
